# Creating an object with a string

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

So, here's the deal. I have an interface called IBehavior. Each one of my Entity's has a variable: `private IBehavior _behavior`. Each Entity also has a variable: `public string Behavior`. Upon loading my entitys the string is filled from an xml file. Subsequently a function called `init()` is called on all entitys. This method takes the string and uses this line of code to call the desired constructor: `Type.GetType(Behavior).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);`.

Unfortunately, the Invoke() method returns something of type Object, and the _behavior variable wont accept this without a cast. I have tried this approach:
`_behavior = (IBehavior)Type.GetType(Behavior).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);`.

All this did was tell me that my `_bahavior` variable was null and therefore this could not happen. I'm probably using `GetConstructor()` incorrectly. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Init Function:

```
public void Init()
{
  if (Behavior == "null" || Behavior == "none")
  {
    _behavior = null;
    return;
  }

  _behavior = (IBehavior) Type.GetType(Behavior).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object(), null);
}
```

Comment: If more information is needed let me know what you'd like to see and I'll add it in an edit.  Also I apologize if this is a repost but I haven't found anything that has solved my problem yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create type from its name use:

```
_behavior = (IBehavior)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(Behavior));
```

The other problem with your code is that you are calling constructor on `new object()` because you use [`MethodBase.Invoke(Object, Object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object(), null)
```

and by specifying only array of object, you use [`ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/6ycw1y17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
_behavior = (IBehavior)Type.GetType(Behavior)
                           .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
                           .Invoke(new object[] { });
```

***Note***: If you receive `ArgumentNullException` from `Activator.CreateInstance`, remember that type must be specified with namespace (if defined in the same assembly), like:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication.SomeClass"))
```

Comment: Thank you. Any Idea why this would cause an ArgumentNullException?

Comment: @user1311199, maybe constructor of created type has a parameter and you are passing `null` to it with `Invoke(new object(), null)`?

Comment: I'm sorry i should have phrased that better, but I replaced `Invoke(new object(), null)` with `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(Behavior));` and `CreateInstance()` is throwing the ArgumentNullException.